# Conditional probability calculation restroom

Tags: probability

There are two mobile restroom stalls at a construction site   where I work. There are also three situations that have an equal chance of occurrence: a. none of them is occupied b. only one of them is occupied c. both are occupied

1. If I were to pick one at random, what is the probability that it is occupied?
2. If it turns out that that first one I go to is occupied and I decide to try the other one, what is the probability that the second one is also occupied?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about probability and [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

> If I were to pick one at random, what is the probability that it is occupied?

It can be either occupied or not (regardless of the other restroom) hence: 50%.

> If it turns out that that first one I go to is occupied and I decide to try the other one, what is the probability that the second one is also occupied?

The other one can be either occupied or not. Again 50%